# Tab widget doesn't scroll whith content in android

Tags: android, android-tabs

[image]

Here, I'm facing an issue while dealing with tab widget. I've implemented it successfully, but what I'm facing here is when I swipe the content (here in image no 1, currently I'm on tab 3), tabs are changing accordingly, but they are not being scrolled. Have a look at image no. 2[image]

Now, in image 2,  I'm on tab 4, but tab is not scrolled here with content. Below is my code,

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTabChangeListener, OnPageChangeListener{  
    private TabHost tabHost;  
    private ViewPager pager; 

 @Override  
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
   tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);  
   pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);  

   tabHost.setup();  
   TabWidget tabwidget=tabHost.getTabWidget();


   Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
   int width = display.getWidth();




   TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);  
   spec.setIndicator("Check In");  
   tabHost.addTab(spec);  

   spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);  
   spec.setIndicator("Buddies");  
   tabHost.addTab(spec);  

   spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);  
   spec.setIndicator("Recommendation");  
   tabHost.addTab(spec); 

   spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab4);  
   spec.setIndicator("Feed");  
   tabHost.addTab(spec); 

   spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab5");  
   spec.setContent(R.id.tab5);  
   spec.setIndicator("Last");  
   tabHost.addTab(spec);

   TextView x = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
   x.setTextSize(10);
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().width = 110;

   TextView x1 = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
   x1.setTextSize(10);
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().width = 90;

   TextView x2 = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
   x2.setTextSize(10);
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().width = 200;

   TextView x3 = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
   x3.setTextSize(10);
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().width = 30;

   TextView x4 = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
   x4.setTextSize(10);
   tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().width = 30;



   pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(this));  
   pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this); 
   tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);  

 }  
    @Override  
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
    {  
         int pageNumber = 0;  
         if(tabId.equals("tab1"))
         {  
              pageNumber = 0;  

         }

         else if(tabId.equals("tab2"))
         {  
              pageNumber = 1;

         }

         else if(tabId.equals("tab3"))
         {  
              pageNumber = 2;  

         }

         else if(tabId.equals("tab4"))
         {  
              pageNumber = 3;  


         }

         else if(tabId.equals("tab5"))
         {  
              pageNumber = 4;  

         }
         else
         {  
              pageNumber = 0;  

         }  

         pager.setCurrentItem(pageNumber);

    } 

    @Override  
    public void onPageSelected(int pageNumber) {  
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(pageNumber);


    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {


    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        View tabView = tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(position);
        if (tabView != null)
        {
            final int width = mHorizontalScroll.getWidth();
            final int scrollPos = tabView.getLeft() - (width - tabView.getWidth()) / 2;
            mHorizontalScroll.scrollTo(scrollPos, 0);
        } else {
            mHorizontalScroll.scrollBy(positionOffsetPixels, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can help you

```
TabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setLayoutParams(newLinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/4)-2,50));
TabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setLayoutParams(newLinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/4)-2,50));
TabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setLayoutParams(newLinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/4)-2,50));
TabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setLayoutParams(newLinearLayout.LayoutParams((width/4)-2,50));
```